# Extra line from new itemize environment in tabular

Tags: environments, itemize, tabularray

I am having problems getting rid of the new line that appears in some cases in a newly defined itemize environment inserted in a tabular array:[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{xitemize}{%
\itemize[nosep,leftmargin=*]
}{\enditemize
\vspace{-0.2em}

}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={X[1]X[2]}, measure=vbox, row{1} = {gray8,font=\bfseries}}
Case & Description \\
\textbf{Without first line} 
& 
\begin{xitemize}
    \item Why
    \item is
    \item a blank line
    \item added?
\end{xitemize}
\\
\textbf{With first line}    
& Test
 \begin{xitemize}
    \item This
    \item is
    \item correct.
\end{xitemize}
\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Try `stretch=-1` option of the `tblr` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, I confirm this solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment by @hair-splitter, the option `stretch=-1` solved my issue:

```
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={p{4cm}X}, measure=vbox, row{1} = {gray8,font=\bfseries}, stretch=-1, rowsep=4pt}

[... table content ...]

\end{tblr}
```

This is discussed in the `tabularray` package documentation:

> From version 2022A (2022-03-01), you can remove extra space above and
> below lists, by adding option stretch=-1.

Adding the option `rowsep=4pt` allows avoiding a too compact rendering of the table.